# Unificar datos como uno solo en MongoDB

Tags: mysql, mongodb, sql, charts

Tengo este dato que toma diferentes valores, pero especificamente tengo un problema en el que debo mostrar como 10G cualquier valor que sea 10, 10G, 10Ge, A-10 y a10.

speed:"10G"

Hay alguna forma de mostrarlo como un solo valor dentro de una consulta para usarlo en mongocharts?

Sería similar al show AS de mysql pero no he encontrado una forma clara, solamente para mostrar colecciones enteras como otro nombre pero no valores especificos

Solo necesito unificar lo que está marcado en azul imgur.com/a/SLveTp1

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar `aggregate` y en el `aggregate` usar `$cond`

No sé cómo esté estructurado tu colección pero podría ser algo así

```
    db.tu_collecion.aggregate(
   [
      {
         $project:
           {

             discount:
               {
                 $cond: { if: { $in: [ "10G", "10Ge" ] }, then: 10G, else:"algo" }
               }
           }
      }
   ]
)
```

Puedes buscar mas información acerca de esto en la [Documentación oficial](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/)

Comment: Me da siempre error de unexpected token. Dejo una captura de la estructura de mi db, No estoy usando mas que filtros de fecha en el query de charts. Solo necesito unificar lo que está marcado en azul

https://imgur.com/a/SLveTp1

Comment: agrega tu colección a la pregunta y cómo haces actualmente la consulta

Comment: Complementé con imagenes el comentario anterior